# Accessing schema metadata in Parquet file through Athena

Tags: parquet

I have some Parquet files in S3, and each has some metadata in the schema:

```
>>> pq = pyarrow.parquet.read_table('file.pq')
>>> pq.schema.metadata.keys()
dict_keys([b'my_metadata_key', b'pandas'])
```

I would like to query that metadata in Athena like a column. I can create a table that accesses the Parquet files like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS database.table (
  `col1` double,
  `col2` double,
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '1'
) LOCATION 's3://my-bucket/my-files/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

...which lets me access the columns, but not the metadata.

I've attempted to find how to do this by reading the Athena and Apache Hive docs, but haven't had any luck. I know that I can access the file paths by using a magic string:

```
select "$path" from database.table
```

so I am wondering whether there is a similar way to access the metadata. I also know I can pass some configuration through the SERDEPROPERTIES argument, but haven't been successful in finding the documentation for this feature if it exists.